# Prometheus multiple source label in relabel config

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

For some reason, my Pod in k8s could possibly labeled with `syscode` or `cib_syscode`, how can I relabel both of them to `cib_syscode`? That is to say if pod labeled with one of them, choose its label value as the result.
I have tried as follow, but it doesn't work because the target_label is duplicate.

```yaml
    - job_name: ncr
      honor_labels: true
      scrape_interval: 30s
      scrape_timeout: 30s
      metrics_path: /metrics
      scheme: http
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_syscode]
        separator: ;
        regex: (.*)
        target_label: cib_syscode
        replacement: ${1}
        action: replace
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_cib_syscode]
        separator: ;
        regex: (.*)
        target_label: cib_syscode
        replacement: ${1}
        action: replace
```

Looking forward to your reply, thank you!

Comment: Did provided solution help you? Did you try it?

Comment: @kkopczak Yes, the solution works.But still exists a small problem, I will describe in the answer zone

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```yaml
    - job_name: ncr
      honor_labels: true
      scrape_interval: 30s
      scrape_timeout: 30s
      metrics_path: /metrics
      scheme: http
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_syscode, __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_cib_syscode]
        separator: ;
        regex: ([^;]+)
        target_label: cib_syscode
        replacement: ${1}
        action: replace
```

If either `__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_syscode` or `__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_cib_syscode` is set, then the regex should select its value (i.e. a continuous string not containing the separator `;`) and assign it to the `cib_syscode` target label.

Answer (score 1):

Found this while fixing the same issue. The answer by **weibeld** is correct by design, but unfortunately that regexp + replacement doesn't work (Prometheus 1.20). This one does:

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_syscode, __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_cib_syscode]
    separator: ;
    regex: '((.*);(.*))'
    target_label: cib_syscode
    replacement: '$2$3'
    action: replace
```

Comment: what if both `syscode` and `cib_syscode` exist? how to get the value in one of them, any one is ok, let's assume  we take the value of `syscode`.@weibeld @taiga-elephant Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution should work as expected even if both `cib_syscode` and `syscode` labels exist at the discovered pod:

```yaml
relabel_configs:
- source_labels:
  - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_cib_syscode
  target_label: cib_syscode
- source_labels:
  - cib_syscode
  - __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_syscode
  regex: ";(.+)"
  target_label: cib_syscode
```

It works in the following way:

- The first relabeling rule extracts `cib_syscode` from `__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_cib_syscode` label.
- The secon relabeling rule is executed only on successfull regex match, e.g. when the `cis_syscode` label is empty after the first step. In this case the `cis_syscode` label
  is set to the value of the `__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_syscode` label.

P.S. You can debug Prometheus relabeling rules at [this page](https://play.victoriametrics.com/select/accounting/1/6a716b0f-38bc-4856-90ce-448fd713e3fe/metric-relabel-debug).

Comment: you saved my day!
If one needs to rename the resulting label, a third step seems necessary:
```
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_cib_syscode]
    target_label: __tmp_syscode
    - source_labels: [__tmp_syscode, __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_another_syscode]
    regex: ";(.+)"
    target_label: __tmp_syscode
    - source_labels: [__tmp_syscode]
    replacement: "prefix-$1"
    target_label: finalsyscode
```